# How do i get the value from addressInformation Magento 2

Tags: sales-order, quote, shipping-address, customer-address, sales-quote

[image]

How do I get the example value which is the date.

```
$billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
$shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
```

these two don't have it

But it saves in `quote_address` table

Comment: If you get value from order then you need to add that fields in sales order table

Comment: I tried that way but wasn't getting the value in that table
it goes in sales_order_address

Comment: $order->getShippingAddress()->getData('example');
 OR
 $order->getShippingAddress()->getExample();

Answer (score 0):

> You need to add that fields in `sales_order_address` table
>
> and then you can get values from order address object
>
> for example

```
    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
    $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
```

> get separate field as well :

```
    $billingcity = $order->getBillingAddress()->getCity();
```

> same things you can get custom fields as well

Comment: It didnt work,
i have the example in sales_order_address and i have the value saved 
but when i do 
$billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
$shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
i dont see it its NULL

Comment: have you check in table , value is there or null ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, It saves in quote_address but its NULL in sales_order_address. I dont know how to get this value in toi sales_order_address

Comment: you can use this for convert quote to slaes

app/code/Vendor/Extension/etc/fieldset.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
  <scope id="global">
      <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_address">
       <field name="custom_module_table_id">
          <aspect name="to_order"/>
       </field>
      </fieldset>
      </scope>
</config>

Comment: if have you useful then up-vote my answer

Comment: Or you can use observer to save fields in sales_order_address
like sales_place_order_after

Comment: custom_module_table_id what do I pass column name?

Comment: how do i use an observer to save field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100045/discussion-between-pradip-garchar-and-jibin-george).